# How to count rows in DataTable / DataBase with 1 basic and 2 specific conditions in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, count, counter

I have question. I need count rows in data base or DataTable using specific conditins.
I have data base with 3 columns like: "case number", "type", "status"
Column "case number" include f.e. 100 rows, but 25 cases for example 1 case include 5 individual some another value.
Column "type" means type of case
Column "status" means current status.

I need something like "Ifcounts" in Excel.

I would like to count f.e. how many rows I have with the same "case number" with some type and status.

I am trying with SQL query but it works only for if I set specific case number, but this is not what I exacly need because I would like to count all cases with conditions.

Is it possible? How? Thank you in advence!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: I think you need a [SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) in conjunction with a [COUNT() aggregate function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is solution:

```
  sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select CaseColumn,  count(*) From mytable WHERE Type = 'X' AND Status = 'Y' GROUP BY CaseColumn"
  sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlite_cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count
```

Thanks for good idea about modify SQL query :)